# Auto remove tab-indents from everything I paste into the Ubuntu CLI?

Tags: command-line, tabs, crossplatform

Is there a utility I could install that will automatically remove ("sift") any tabulation indents from code blocks and heredocuments I paste into the Ubuntu CLI?

### For example, if I paste:

```
    (
    command1
    command2
    )
```

Or

```
    cat <<-'PMA' > /opt/script.sh
    string1
    string2
    PMA
```

### In pasting, these will become:

```
(
command1
command2
)
```

Or

```
cat <<-'PMA' > /opt/script.sh
string1
string2
PMA
```

### To further clarify:

My aim is that **between pasting to execution** all leading tabulations (and maybe also spaces), will be deleted.

Comment: why though? Wordsplitting destroys extra whitespace anyway... it makes no difference to the command

Comment: Something like this would work I guess: `sed -i -e "s/^\s\{1,\}//g filename"`, [here](https://superuser.com/questions/112834/how-to-match-whitespace-in-sed).

Comment: @Zanna, what you say is interesting --- In my machines it doesn't happen when I combine a cat heredoc inside the block. I believe that if you will try that in your PC when it includes a cat heredoc, you will notice execution break as well...

Comment: oh I see what you mean, yes you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `bind -u complete`, then Bash will behave exactly as you want: it will not allow you to input tabs.

Source: [This answer on "Disable bash tab completion"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/178973/117037)

Comment: But I don't want to destroy the whole tab completion. I want no tabs only in my specific codes.

Comment: @Benia I don't think that's possible. Bash can't tell the difference between typing a character and pasting a character.